# Hover over element, change opacity on child?

Tags: css

```
<li>
    <img src="m.jpg">
    <div class="img-data">img name</div>
</li>
```

Is it possible using just css to show .img-data on hover of the li?
.img-data has opacity set at zero currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```css
ul {
  list-style: none
}

.img-data {
  opacity: 0
}

li:hover .img-data {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img height="60" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <div class="img-data">img name</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```